# Add a Table of frequencies to a boxplot in R

Tags: r

I tried to add some information to a boxplot.
Especially i wanted to add frequencies stored in a table.
I tried the plotrix package but did not succeed.
Can you give me a hint?

Here is what i tried

```
library(plotrix)
boxplot(iris,   
     col = "blue", 
     main = "Boxplot des Irisdatensatzes",
     sub = "alle Variablen (Untertitel)",  
     xlab = "Variablen des Irisdatensatzes",
     ylab = "Angaben in \n inch")
tab<-table(iris$Species)
addtable2plot(0.7 ,8,tab,bty="o",title="The table")
```

Comment: According to `?addtable2plot`, `table` is "a data frame, matrix or similar object that will be displayed". You should try to convert the output of `table` to one of these objects.

Comment: i really did not take this into account because the functions name suggests it would add a table to a plot. I did use tab<-as.matrix(table(iris$Species)) and all went well. THANkS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Pascals comment, I've used `tab<-as.matrix(table(iris$Species))` and it worked!